OpenAPI validator that supports a custom dialect
I am trying to create my own keywords as part of an OpenAPI spec (I am using OpenAPI 3.1.0). From what I can tell, to do this I would have to create my own JSON schema dialect and then use the jsonSchemaDialect OpenAPI property to refer to my custom dialect, which contains my custom keywords.
Are there any tools out there that can validate an OpenAPI spec that uses the jsonSchemaDialect property? I have been using swagger editor to validate my spec so far but it seems to not support the jsonSchemaDialect property.
I am also interested to know whether any validator implementations exist in Typescript and Java (or Kotlin) that support this.

It supports custom dialects but only a few selected ones, but I would venture to guess the owner would be willing to update his package if you requested it accept any value  https://www.GitHub.com/hyperjump-io/json-schema

You can do all of this with @hyperjump/json-schema. See, here for how to create a custom dialect and here for how to validate an OpenAPI document using any dialect including your custom one. The code examples in the blog post are out of date, but the concepts still hold.
